# Remote Control Qbittorrent over Internet

Tags: ubuntu, bittorrent

So I want to access Qbittorrent WebUI from internet so that I can connect to it using http://x.x.x.x:8080 where x.x.x.x is my public ip not the private. For this I activated th WebUi fucntion with UPnP box checked on Qbit's options>webui. Now I can access the webui over the private network i.e. currently http://192.168.0.101:8080 opens the webUI but when I try it using my public ip, it doesn't.
I am using a DLink Router and connected to WLAN.
I am getting my  Public IP googling 'whats my ip'.
WEBUI port is at default 8080.
Software Information:
OS: Ubuntu 15.10
Qbit: v3.2.3
Router: Dlink 605L

What I tried so far( it didn't worked):

1. Checking Upnp on router setting.
2. on ubuntu terminal , 'sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT'

And nothing is working, can anyone who has done this before guide me what step I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to port forward on the router. There are countless guides online to follow.

Comment: @Linef4ult Even done that, it is not working.